# How to use selectCase() in JPA specifications

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have table with name `workorder` with the columns `id,shift,date,sop_no,type`
User will be passing a integer to GET API to filter table content. if the record is of `type=P` then use the `shift` column to filter the data otherwise use `sop_no`  I have following snippet of code. I'm using JPA specifications.

```
workorderRepo.findAll(Specification.where(hasShift(Integer a))
```

```
    public Specification<WorkOrder> hasShift(Integer a) {

        return ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            Predicate nonP = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("sop_no"),a);
            Predicate P = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("shift"),a);
            retrun criteriaBuilder.selectCase().when(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("type"), "P"), P).otherwise(nonP);


        });

    }
```

I'm using `selectCase()` for select `nonP` or `P` predicate
But code construct throwing  **Expression<Object> cannot be converted to Predicate** Error

I tried convert `selectCase()` to `Predicate` type using `as` method but no use

Answer (score 0):

I used the following code to serve the purpose

```
 public Specification<WorkOrder> hasShift(Integer a) {

    return ((root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Predicate nonP = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("sop_no"),a);
        Predicate P = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("shift"),a);
        Predicate isP = criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("type"), "P");
        Predicate one=criteriaBuilder.and(isP,P);
        Predicate two =criteriaBuilder.and(nonP);
        return criteriaBuilder.or(one,two);
    });

}
```